# the battery power is limited on mobile devices

Tags: grammaticality

May I know which one is grammatical?

> the battery power is limited on mobile devices
>
> the battery powers are limited on mobile devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Power is uncountable, so it's the first one.

> the battery power is limited on mobile devices

Comment: Rather, "power" is uncountable when it means "energy".  Consider: "her superhero powers included unaided flight and mind-reading" :)

Comment: I actually thought about that. Decided that batteries should not have superpowers. Most inanimate objects just don't have the required responsibilities.

Comment: The battery is dead. Before it died, was it animate? The powers that be are undecided.